# Y axis text cutoff when make html to pdf using html2pdf library?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

I am using Html2pdf to export my webpage to pdf. My chart looks great on web, but upon exporting to pdf some highchart text cut off from the last pdf page. The charts on other pages are working perfect.

Screenshots of an original chart and its pdf display.
[image]

[image]

And my code is

```
document.getElementById("download-btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
        var downloadFile = document.querySelector(".downloadpage");
        console.log("downloadFile");
        console.log(downloadFile);
    console.log(window);
    var opt = {
            margin: 0.1,
            filename: 'Report.pdf',
            image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
            html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
            jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: [14.7, 16.5], orientation: 'landscape' },
        pagebreak: { mode: ['avoid-all', 'css', 'legacy'] }
                            
        };
    html2pdf().from(downloadFile).set(opt).save();
    })
window.onload= function(){
    
}
```

What can I do to make this work?
There is any property from the library to fix it ?

Comment: From Highcharts perspective, you should use the Highcharts-export module to achieve it. https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview Other solutions and custom libraries are not supported.

Comment: The web page contains Data tables and other elements also. So I need the whole html page to PDF. Thats why I using custom library.

Comment: I see. Are you able to reproduce this issue on some online editor?